# web3.eth.Contract passing nonce

Tags: ethereum, web3js, nonce

I use `web3.eth.Contract` to interact with smart contract. I need to execute method multiple times at the same moment asynchronously. Because of nonce things I have errors like `replacement transaction underpriced` so I need to increase `nonce` manually. But I can't find a way to do it, here is example how I call method:

```
contract.methods.foo()
            .send({
                from: address,
                gas: 100000,
                gasPrice: gasPrice
            });
```

How to pass `nonce` by going this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nonce` is one of the allowed parameters overriding the transaction.

So you can do

```
contract.methods.foo().send({
    from: address,
    gas: 100000,
    gasPrice: gasPrice,
    nonce: 5
});
```

Source: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.10.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send

---

> replacement transaction underpriced

This error occurs when there's already another transaction with the same nonce in the mempool, and your new transaction (with the same nonce) has lower or the same `gasPrice`.